# Insertar valores actualizados en una tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla que se llama tipos_valores_viajes que tiene 3 campos.

```
cod_tipo_viaje
fecha_desde
valor_km
```

Primer campo es un autonumerico, segundo la ultima fecha desde la que rige el valor, y valor_km es el importe.

La tabla se ve asi:

```
'1', '2013-07-26', '1.000'

'1', '2013-09-06', '1.100'

'1', '2013-10-10', '1.600'

'1', '2013-11-10', '1.900'

'1', '2013-12-02', '2.100'

'1', '2018-01-02', '20.000'

'2', '2013-07-26', '3.200'

'2', '2013-09-09', '3.520'

'2', '2013-10-23', '5.120'

'2', '2013-11-06', '6.080'

'2', '2018-01-02', '25.000'

'2', '2018-03-05', '30.000'

'3', '2013-09-08', '5.500'

'3', '2013-11-07', '7.500'

'3', '2014-01-10', '10.000'

'3', '2018-02-01', '101.000'

'4', '2013-08-22', '10.000'

'4', '2013-10-06', '15.000'

'4', '2018-03-01', '150.000'
```

Yo tengo que insertar un nuevo registro en cada tipo de viaje con la siguiente regla:
Si el valor_km es menor a 100, entonces se aumenta un 25%, si es mayor o igual, un 30%. Y el importe se debe hacer efectivo 7 dias desde la ultima fecha.
Por poner un ejemplo, para el cod_tipo_viaje 1, deberia haber un nuevo registro que sea:

```
'1', '2018-01-09', '25.000'
```

La query que yo utilice es esta:

```
insert into tipos_viajes_valores (cod_tipo_viaje,fecha_desde,valor_km)

select tvv.cod_tipo_viaje, date_add(tvv.fecha_desde, interval 7 day)

,   case 

    when tvv.valor_km < 100 then tvv.valor_km = tvv.valor_km * 1.25

    when tvv.valor_km >= 100 then tvv.valor_km = tvv.valor_km * 1.3

    end

from tipos_viajes_valores tvv

inner join (

select val.cod_tipo_viaje, max(val.fecha_desde) as 'max_fecha'

from tipos_viajes_valores val

where val.fecha_desde <= current_date()

group by 1 ) as maximas

on tvv.cod_tipo_viaje=maximas.cod_tipo_viaje

and tvv.fecha_desde=maximas.max_fecha;
```

Inserta el nuevo registro pero el `valor_km` me figura en 0 en vez de hacerme el aumento, por que sera?

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente lo que esta mal es:

```
case 
   when tvv.valor_km < 100 then tvv.valor_km = tvv.valor_km * 1.25
   when tvv.valor_km >= 100 then tvv.valor_km = tvv.valor_km * 1.3
end
```

Por ejemplo, esto `tvv.valor_km = tvv.valor_km * 1.25` como resultado del `when` es inválido en otras bases de datos, sin embargo, esta sintaxis en MySql es válida, pero el sentido es muy distinto al que estarías esperando, en este caso lo que se está evaluando es la igualdad de `valor_km` con `valor_km * 1.25`, cosa que obviamente es falsa y el falso se "coerciona" al `0`. La solución es quitar la asignación que haces:

```
case 
   when tvv.valor_km < 100 then tvv.valor_km * 1.25
   when tvv.valor_km >= 100 then tvv.valor_km * 1.3
end
```